# how to access local event log using local ip address in c#

Tags: c#, wmi, event-viewer

I can access the local system  event log information using "." and "Machinename". but i cannnot access the local system event log by using ip address.

the code is:

```
EventLog Logs = new EventLog("Application",".");//EventLog("Application","Machinename");
```

this also works fine. but when i am using it for ip address like

```
EventLog Logs = new EventLog("Application","XXX.XX.X.X");
```

please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting the IP address to a host name using `Dns.GetHostEntry`:

```
using System.Net;

string hostName = Dns.GetHostEntry("xxx.xx.x.x").HostName.Split('.')[0];
    EventLog log = new EventLog("Application", hostName);
```

Comment: to access the Dns.GetHostEntry(), any namespaces needed...?

Comment: @Gomathipriya in System.Net

Comment: Thanks mike i find it, and your code is working fine. i have another doubt, suppose if it is remote host and have a credentials means how to access it